# Iframe displays as literal in CMS

Tags: html, iframe

*Similar question asked earlier which has since been deleted. Hoping this one is clearer*

I added an iframe via tinyMCE to my website page manager.

But, the output quotes (") the iframe element under a p tag so the actual snippet is displayed.

[image]

[image]

I pasted the snippet into a page manager on my CMS. Is there anything I can add before the snippet to remove the effect of the quotes?

Here is the snippet:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1at55AGTr0LUc6--WKiuS0Vs1Ldn8ZgbrDoYiU0KlpkM/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Rather than meddle witht he code ont he site itself, I'd rather fiddle with the snippet. Is there a way escape the double quotations effect seen in the image above? I tried just adding quote marks att he beginning int he hope that the output would close the opened ones. No luck.

Comment: As far as I can remember, there's some setting on tinyMCE to get rid of these quotes.

Comment: Is there an option in the CMS to enter raw HTML - some of them allow that

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes, thanks for the tip. The raw html view allowed me to paste as desired. But, that seems to have led to another, separate problem. Thanks though!